# Get ID of HTML element to store in table / Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building an application in Rails that allows the user to upload a photo and then select one of four overlays that eventually will be composited onto it with Paperclip.

I'm new to Rails and I haven't been able to figure out how I pull the ID of a HTML element and store it in my database - I have this code:

```
<div>  
 <span id="overlay"></span>
</div>

<div id="overlay-select">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><img id="overlay1" src="<%= asset_path '/assets/overlays/pink1.png' %>" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img id="overlay2" src="<%= asset_path '/assets/overlays/green1.png' %>" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img id="overlay3" src="<%= asset_path '/assets/overlays/blue1.png' %>" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img id="overlay4" src="<%= asset_path '/assets/overlays/orange1.png' %>" /></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And what happens is the user clicks #overlay1 - 4, and that img is then cloned and inserted into the #overlay span. I need to be able to grab the ID of whatever img is present in #overlay when the user saves the entry, I've looked for solutions as I don't know where to start but have come up short so far - any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When the user saves you must be submitting some sort of form to the server. You just need to add a hidden field to the form to hold the id. You can set the value of the hidden id field at the same time you clone and insert the img tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are facing two issues. You cannot just clone the image, because you are using an id on these images. IDs must be unique. If you just clone the image, you could run into all sorts of js trouble, where element targetting fails and such. With that said, you can get around this by using a data attribute. Sample below.

**Your html would remain similar except for the ids.**

```
<div>  
 <span id="overlay"></span>
</div>

<div id="overlay-select">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><img data-overlayid="overlay1" src="<%= asset_path '/assets/overlays/pink1.png' %>" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img data-overlayid="overlay2" src="<%= asset_path '/assets/overlays/green1.png' %>" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img data-overlayid="overlay3" src="<%= asset_path '/assets/overlays/blue1.png' %>" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img data-overlayid="overlay4" src="<%= asset_path '/assets/overlays/orange1.png' %>" /></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Your js would be. Would recommend using javascript for this. Also you will need to use ajax to actuallly send this to the server, unless you plan to do it using a post, or get method.

```
function getImgId(){

    //Data for span
    var overlaySpan = document.getElementById('overlay'),
        imgs = overlaySpan.getElementsByTagName('img'),
        imgsLn = imgs.length,
        relevantSrc,//filled with relevant image source
        relevantID;//filled with id of elem

    if(imgLn > 0){//If there are any images
        relevantSrc = imgs[0].src;

        //Data for imagelist.
        var overlaySelector = document.getElementById('overlay-select'),
            overlayImgItems = overlaySelector.getElementsByTagName('img');//Would be most efficient to use query selector but then browser support would be sacrificed

        for(var i=0;i<overlayImgItems.length;i++){
            var imgItem = overlayImgItems[i];
            if(imgItem.src === relevantSrc){
            relevantID = imgItem.getAttribute('data-overlayid');
            break;
        }
    }
    return relevantID;
}
```

Comment: You're right - I hadn't realised the issue with cloning unique IDs.

I'll try out your JS solution too, thanks for the help!